# How to use a variable from __init__ in another function

Tags: python, class, scope

I am trying to use `var1` which is the variable for a Tkinter `Checkbutton` in another function but I keep getting a `TypeError` which I am assuming is a result of `var1` being local in scope to `__init__`. Normally, I would just return `var1` (in order to use it in another function) but in this case I am not sure what to do.

```py
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        var1 = tk.IntVar() # <-- local var1 variable
        self.include_subf = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text="Include subfolders", variable=var1,
                                            onvalue=1, offvalue=0)

    def a_function(self):
        if var1.get() == 1: # <-- want to use var1 here
            pass
```

Comment: Hint: see where the code says `self.include_subf = ...`? Have you noticed how this allows you to use `self.include_subf` elsewhere in the code? Do you understand why that works? What happens if you try using the same technique for `var1`?

Comment: Yeah I understand it now. I am pretty new to OOP. How would I go about using a function in an __init__ function in another class function?

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to say there, possibly because the words don't mean what you intend them to mean, but mainly because I can't imagine what kind of "using" you have in mind. Please try to come up with actual code that illustrated the problem, and then ask a new question in a new post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a class is for. Rather than saving the value into a local variable `var1` save it as an attribute (a variable belonging to the class instance across its entire lifespan) with `self.var1 = ...`. Then you can access it in all the other instance methods with `self.var1`.

Comment: How would I go about using a function in an init function in another class function?

Comment: Can you clarify please or provide an example? I don't understand what you're asking.